# How to implement single sign on for cross domain website

Tags: single-sign-on

I need to implement single sign on for multiple cross domain website. For example I have three website www.example.com,www.example1.com,www.example2.com. If I am login to one of website I should be able to access all other website. All my website are using .net as backend and angular/angularjs as front-end.

Comment: Are you interested in conforming to OIDC?

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup some Identity Provider (IDP) then you can user OIDC to connect you all applications to IDP and achieve SSO.

For IDP, you can use free solutions like Identity Server or enterprise solutions like Okta, OneLogin,Idaptive etc.
The general flow will be as:

1. User tries too login to client application
2. Redirect the user to IDP with clientId, unique for that application
3. User enters their credentials in IDP login page and is authenticated in the IDP
4. If the authentication is successful, user is redirected back to application with id_token (JWT)
5. Client app receives the id_token and confirms the signature using the public key
6. If everything is successful, user's session is established for client application

Comment: It's always easier said than done. The real challenge here is how can you share the JWT or the session ID in general with all other domains?